# find out speed of android device using GPS

Tags: android, location

In my application I am retriving speed of a device using getSpeed() method of Location class.
It gives speed in meters/sec. To convert this value to km/hr I am multiplying this with 3.6. Then storing it in sqlite database. But I am getting wrong speed. ex. 580 when it is moving with speed of 40km/hr. This is my code:

```
    float mps = location.getSpeed();        
    float kmh = (float) (mps*3.6);
    String speed = String.valueOf(kmh);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"speed: "+speed,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
```

Where is It going wrong. I have googled for this but could find the same method.

Comment: Which provider are you using ? If you are using networkProvider, its highly inaccurate for this kinda usage.

Comment: These kinda usage should go through error correction algorithms, since you cant use every sample of data here. You need to get 3 samples and use its average to determine which of the samples are really bad.

Comment: @Siddharth this does not explain the 580km/h

Comment: yup I am using networkProvider. but is it that bad. What else can be done

Comment: There is nothing to explain here, network provider is bad, it calculates time based on gps differences and time differences (obviously), and if network provider gps is bad, so will the calculation be. You need to use gpsprovider and test.

Comment: oops sory for mistake. I am using gps provider only. I got a little confused.

Comment: could you add a condition clause like: "if (accuracy is higher than 10m) { do speed calculation } else (waiting for better location)" ? AFAK, Google's "Location Aware (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/index.html )" example shows how to determine the location's accuracy.